# How to add a new user to AddThis service automatically for setting analytics service

Tags: c#, javascript, api, jquery-mobile, addthis

I'm building a web site (Backoffice) that offers a mobile website to my customers.

the mobile website structure is the same for all users.

I want to add a "Report" tab in the back office, with analytics information using AddThis service, so every user will be able to watch his mobile website statistics.

From what i understand, i need to add the AddThis javascript analytics code to every customers (meaning every mobile website) along with a pubid number.

How do I get a new pubid number automatically for every new user that signs in?

I'm sure there is an easier solution.

I'm a new developer, I'm developing the back office in C# and the mobile website with jQquery mobile and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new profile for each site and have a new pubid generated.  Profiles can be created by going to your Settings section and clicking on "Profiles" in the left navigation.  Then you'll be able to query for a site's analytics using their pubid.

Info on profiles: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381216-using-profiles#.UFczpaSXRuo

Info on Analytics API: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381264-addthis-analytics-api#.UFc0MaSXRuo